# correct way to download mutiple mysql databases from remote server to local computer

Tags: mysql, database

I want to copy multiple MySQL databases that are hosted by a remote hosting company.

There are over 100 large databases so obviously I need a way to be able to download them all at the same time.

I have searched on-line for the correct and most secure way to do this. I realize that it **must** be done via **command line** on my computer.

I also realize that instruction like this is the right way to proceed:

```
mysqldump -u remoteusername -p remotepassword -h your.site.com databasename > dump.sql

mysql -u localusername -p localpassword databasename < dump.sql
```

**my confusion** is that I presumed that I need to connect to the external database **via SSH**?

If so, then I would really appreciate any advice on how to connect to the MySQL server via SSH.

I have searched this on-line but cannot seem to find any clear information or guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

The program "mysqldump" is a command-line program. *You* don't connect to a database; "mysqldump" connects to a database.

*You* login to a server (host). It *might* be the same server the dbms is running on, but it doesn't have to be. If you're running a web site on a shared host (a common scenario), the web site and the dbms usually run on two different servers. Your login *might* be through ssh, and it might not.

You login to a server that offers either

- shell access (usually a bash shell), or
- a graphical interface that lets you dump a MySQL database.

*Exactly* how to do any of these can vary a little from host to host. But an ssh connection usually looks something like this.

```
$ ssh username@hostname.com
```

Also, the MySQL username might or might not be the same as the login username.